# Groupby and interpolate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, pandas-groupby

I have data that has a week number, account id, and several usage columns. I'd like to a) group by account ID, b) resample weekly data into daily, and c) interpolate daily data evenly (divide the weekly by 7), then bring it all back together. I've got most of it down, but Pandas `groupby` confuses me a little. It's also very slow, which makes me think this might not be the optimal solution.

Data looks like this:

```
    Account Id  year week         views stats foo_col 
31133   213     2017-03-05          4.0     2.0     11.0
10085   456     2017-03-12          1.0     6.0     3.0
49551   789     2017-03-26          1.0     6.0     27.0
```

Here's my code:

```
def interpolator(mini_df):
    mini_df = mini_df[cols_to_interpolate].set_index('year week')
    return mini_df.resample('D').ffill().interpolate() / 7

example = list(grp)[0][1]
interpolator(example) # This works perfectly

df.groupby('Account Id').agg(interpolator)                # doesn't work
df.groupby('Account Id').transform(interpolator)          # doesn't work

for name,group in grp:
    group = group[cols_to_interpolate].set_index('year week')
    group = group.resample('D').ffill().interpolate() / 7 # doesn't work

for acc_id in df['Account Id'].unique():
    mask = df.loc[df['Account Id'] == acc_id]
    print(df[mask])                                     # doesn't work
```

Comment: How working `df.groupby('Account Id').apply(interpolator)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope your function should be chained with `groupby` object like:

```
df = (df.set_index('year week')
        .groupby('Account Id')[cols_to_interpolate]
        .resample('D')
        .ffill()
        .interpolate() / 7)
```

Solution from comments is different - `interpolate` is apply for each group:

```
df.groupby('Account Id').apply(interpolator)
```

Comment: thanks - the second one works. For the first one, I need to take a subset (`df[cols_to_interpolate]`) because some of them are not numeric, so not sure if it works?

Comment: thanks jezrael, you are amazing - your answers have helped me many times in the past :)

Comment: question: are the results of these two methods different?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - ya, it depends of data in my opinion. Because `ffill` replace all NaNs values by forward filling. Only not replace NaNs which are first in groups (not 100% sure, but possible NaNs values in input). So only these NaNs are replaced by interpolate.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - Also if check `df.set_index('year week')
        .groupby('Account Id')[cols_to_interpolate]
        .resample('D')
        .ffill()` it return DataFrame, so `interploate` working not with groups, but with all rows.