# Pandas efficiently interpolate sections of a larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bloomberg

I have data coming in via the bloomberg API, the returned dataframe is a large singular dataframe
(66 rows, 5 cols) and then sent out in one block via websocket as a singular JSON str.

I need to linearly/ simple interpolate this 66 row dataframe, however this interpolation must be performed separately for each currency (e.g. KWN = Korean Won, the price is around 1190, whereas for Chinese yuan is only around 6, so we can't interpolated between currencies).

I am currently very inefficiently filtering my dataframe on the index.str so that the first 3 chars match the iterated chosen currency.

I will be very very grateful if anyone has any ideas to help speed this all up/ tips. thanks very much :)

```
        self.ccy_prefix = ['KWN', 'IRN', 'NTN', 'IHN', 'PPN', 'CCN']
        for ccy in self.ccy_prefix:
            #interp for each section
            df[df.index.str[:3]==ccy] = df[df.index.str[:3]==ccy].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

[image: Filtered for Korean Wont, note the NAN at the +4Y tenor]

This does successfully work, however it is very slow and inefficient, is there a way to use a map or some other clever Pandas method, I'd attempted to find an alternative but couldn't find anything thus far.

Filtered interpolated DF:
[image]

Large singular DataFrame:
[image]

Raw DataFrame:

```py
{'BID': {'KWN+1W BGN Curncy': 1192.83, 'KWN+1M BGN Curncy': 1193.46, 'KWN+2M BGN Curncy': 1194.2, 'KWN+3M BGN Curncy': 1194.68, 'KWN+6M BGN Curncy': 1195.74, 'KWN+9M BGN Curncy': 1196.15, 'KWN+12M BGN Curncy': 1195.99, 'KWN+2Y BGN Curncy': 1195.57, 'KWN+3Y BGN Curncy': 1194.0, 'KWN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'KWN+5Y BGN Curncy': 1188.95, 'IRN+1W BGN Curncy': 74.61, 'IRN+1M BGN Curncy': 74.83, 'IRN+2M BGN Curncy': 75.07, 'IRN+3M BGN Curncy': 75.51, 'IRN+6M BGN Curncy': 76.37, 'IRN+9M BGN Curncy': 77.22, 'IRN+12M BGN Curncy': 78.07, 'IRN+2Y BGN Curncy': 81.63, 'IRN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IRN+4Y BGN Curncy': 87.98, 'IRN+5Y BGN Curncy': 91.65, 'NTN+1W BGN Curncy': 27.576, 'NTN+1M BGN Curncy': 27.517, 'NTN+2M BGN Curncy': 27.442, 'NTN+3M BGN Curncy': 27.372, 'NTN+6M BGN Curncy': 27.174, 'NTN+9M BGN Curncy': 26.98, 'NTN+12M BGN Curncy': 26.784, 'NTN+2Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+1W BGN Curncy': 14337.8, 'IHN+1M BGN Curncy': 14369.2, 'IHN+2M BGN Curncy': 14417.0, 'IHN+3M BGN Curncy': 14448.8, 'IHN+6M BGN Curncy': 14595.9, 'IHN+9M BGN Curncy': 14703.8, 'IHN+12M BGN Curncy': 14896.0, 'IHN+2Y BGN Curncy': 15504.8, 'IHN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'PPN+1W BGN Curncy': 51.58, 'PPN+1M BGN Curncy': 51.81, 'PPN+2M BGN Curncy': 52.01, 'PPN+3M BGN Curncy': 52.15, 'PPN+6M BGN Curncy': 52.56, 'PPN+9M BGN Curncy': 52.89, 'PPN+12M BGN Curncy': 53.17, 'PPN+2Y BGN Curncy': 54.32, 'PPN+3Y BGN Curncy': 55.68, 'PPN+4Y BGN Curncy': 56.46, 'PPN+5Y BGN Curncy': 57.72, 'CCN+1W BGN Curncy': 6.361, 'CCN+1M BGN Curncy': 6.373, 'CCN+2M BGN Curncy': 6.3853, 'CCN+3M BGN Curncy': 6.3976, 'CCN+6M BGN Curncy': 6.428, 'CCN+9M BGN Curncy': 6.4541, 'CCN+12M BGN Curncy': 6.4776, 'CCN+2Y BGN Curncy': 6.5653, 'CCN+3Y BGN Curncy': 6.6229, 'CCN+4Y BGN Curncy': 6.7332, 'CCN+5Y BGN Curncy': 6.8305}, 'ASK': {'KWN+1W BGN Curncy': 1193.65, 'KWN+1M BGN Curncy': 1194.46, 'KWN+2M BGN Curncy': 1195.2, 'KWN+3M BGN Curncy': 1195.72, 'KWN+6M BGN Curncy': 1197.06, 'KWN+9M BGN Curncy': 1197.48, 'KWN+12M BGN Curncy': 1197.81, 'KWN+2Y BGN Curncy': 1197.28, 'KWN+3Y BGN Curncy': 1195.0, 'KWN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'KWN+5Y BGN Curncy': 1189.95, 'IRN+1W BGN Curncy': 74.65, 'IRN+1M BGN Curncy': 74.88, 'IRN+2M BGN Curncy': 75.12, 'IRN+3M BGN Curncy': 75.56, 'IRN+6M BGN Curncy': 76.42, 'IRN+9M BGN Curncy': 77.28, 'IRN+12M BGN Curncy': 78.14, 'IRN+2Y BGN Curncy': 81.68, 'IRN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IRN+4Y BGN Curncy': 89.98, 'IRN+5Y BGN Curncy': 91.99, 'NTN+1W BGN Curncy': 27.606, 'NTN+1M BGN Curncy': 27.533, 'NTN+2M BGN Curncy': 27.472, 'NTN+3M BGN Curncy': 27.402, 'NTN+6M BGN Curncy': 27.204, 'NTN+9M BGN Curncy': 27.014, 'NTN+12M BGN Curncy': 26.829, 'NTN+2Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+1W BGN Curncy': 14378.0, 'IHN+1M BGN Curncy': 14401.0, 'IHN+2M BGN Curncy': 14439.0, 'IHN+3M BGN Curncy': 14499.7, 'IHN+6M BGN Curncy': 14652.1, 'IHN+9M BGN Curncy': 14803.2, 'IHN+12M BGN Curncy': 14965.0, 'IHN+2Y BGN Curncy': 15545.2, 'IHN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'PPN+1W BGN Curncy': 51.63, 'PPN+1M BGN Curncy': 51.86, 'PPN+2M BGN Curncy': 52.07, 'PPN+3M BGN Curncy': 52.22, 'PPN+6M BGN Curncy': 52.6, 'PPN+9M BGN Curncy': 52.99, 'PPN+12M BGN Curncy': 53.29, 'PPN+2Y BGN Curncy': 54.4, 'PPN+3Y BGN Curncy': 55.8, 'PPN+4Y BGN Curncy': 57.06, 'PPN+5Y BGN Curncy': 58.1, 'CCN+1W BGN Curncy': 6.366, 'CCN+1M BGN Curncy': 6.3781, 'CCN+2M BGN Curncy': 6.3911, 'CCN+3M BGN Curncy': 6.4026, 'CCN+6M BGN Curncy': 6.433, 'CCN+9M BGN Curncy': 6.4591, 'CCN+12M BGN Curncy': 6.4846, 'CCN+2Y BGN Curncy': 6.5753, 'CCN+3Y BGN Curncy': 6.6441, 'CCN+4Y BGN Curncy': 6.7483, 'CCN+5Y BGN Curncy': 6.8405}, 'MID': {'KWN+1W BGN Curncy': 1193.24, 'KWN+1M BGN Curncy': 1193.96, 'KWN+2M BGN Curncy': 1194.7, 'KWN+3M BGN Curncy': 1195.2, 'KWN+6M BGN Curncy': 1196.4, 'KWN+9M BGN Curncy': 1196.82, 'KWN+12M BGN Curncy': 1196.9, 'KWN+2Y BGN Curncy': 1196.42, 'KWN+3Y BGN Curncy': 1194.5, 'KWN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'KWN+5Y BGN Curncy': 1189.45, 'IRN+1W BGN Curncy': 74.63, 'IRN+1M BGN Curncy': 74.85, 'IRN+2M BGN Curncy': 75.09, 'IRN+3M BGN Curncy': 75.53, 'IRN+6M BGN Curncy': 76.4, 'IRN+9M BGN Curncy': 77.25, 'IRN+12M BGN Curncy': 78.1, 'IRN+2Y BGN Curncy': 81.65, 'IRN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IRN+4Y BGN Curncy': 88.98, 'IRN+5Y BGN Curncy': 91.82, 'NTN+1W BGN Curncy': 27.591, 'NTN+1M BGN Curncy': 27.525, 'NTN+2M BGN Curncy': 27.457, 'NTN+3M BGN Curncy': 27.387, 'NTN+6M BGN Curncy': 27.189, 'NTN+9M BGN Curncy': 26.997, 'NTN+12M BGN Curncy': 26.806, 'NTN+2Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+1W BGN Curncy': 14357.9, 'IHN+1M BGN Curncy': 14385.1, 'IHN+2M BGN Curncy': 14428.0, 'IHN+3M BGN Curncy': 14474.2, 'IHN+6M BGN Curncy': 14624.0, 'IHN+9M BGN Curncy': 14753.5, 'IHN+12M BGN Curncy': 14930.5, 'IHN+2Y BGN Curncy': 15525.0, 'IHN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+5Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'PPN+1W BGN Curncy': 51.6, 'PPN+1M BGN Curncy': 51.83, 'PPN+2M BGN Curncy': 52.04, 'PPN+3M BGN Curncy': 52.18, 'PPN+6M BGN Curncy': 52.58, 'PPN+9M BGN Curncy': 52.94, 'PPN+12M BGN Curncy': 53.23, 'PPN+2Y BGN Curncy': 54.36, 'PPN+3Y BGN Curncy': 55.74, 'PPN+4Y BGN Curncy': 56.76, 'PPN+5Y BGN Curncy': 57.91, 'CCN+1W BGN Curncy': 6.3635, 'CCN+1M BGN Curncy': 6.3755, 'CCN+2M BGN Curncy': 6.3882, 'CCN+3M BGN Curncy': 6.4001, 'CCN+6M BGN Curncy': 6.4305, 'CCN+9M BGN Curncy': 6.4566, 'CCN+12M BGN Curncy': 6.4811, 'CCN+2Y BGN Curncy': 6.5703, 'CCN+3Y BGN Curncy': 6.6335, 'CCN+4Y BGN Curncy': 6.7408, 'CCN+5Y BGN Curncy': 6.8355}, 'LAST_BID_TIME_TODAY_REALTIME': {'KWN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 41), 'KWN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 35), 'KWN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'KWN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 34), 'KWN+4Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'KWN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 31), 'IRN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(19, 50, 20), 'IRN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 49), 'IRN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 48), 'IRN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 48), 'IRN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 48), 'IRN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 43), 'IRN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 48), 'IRN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 32, 12), 'IRN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IRN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(8, 45, 3), 'IRN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 35), 'NTN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 17), 'NTN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 35), 'NTN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 30), 'NTN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 30), 'NTN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 31, 30), 'NTN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(18, 0, 42), 'NTN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(18, 0, 42), 'NTN+2Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'NTN+3Y BGN Curncy': NaT, 'NTN+4Y BGN Curncy': NaT, 'NTN+5Y BGN Curncy': NaT, 'IHN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 26), 'IHN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 51), 'IHN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 11), 'IHN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 51), 'IHN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 51), 'IHN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 0, 21), 'IHN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 51), 'IHN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(19, 27, 44), 'IHN+3Y BGN Curncy': nan, 'IHN+4Y BGN Curncy': NaT, 'IHN+5Y BGN Curncy': NaT, 'PPN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 11), 'PPN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 54), 'PPN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 54), 'PPN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 54), 'PPN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 54), 'PPN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(19, 46, 19), 'PPN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 33, 54), 'PPN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(16, 5, 40), 'PPN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'PPN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'PPN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 56), 'CCN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 34, 28), 'CCN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 32, 13), 'CCN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 32, 40), 'CCN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 32, 13), 'CCN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.time(20, 23, 29)}, 'SETTLEMENT_DATE_RT': {'KWN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27, 0, 0), 'KWN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'KWN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'KWN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'KWN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 20, 0, 0), 'KWN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 'KWN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'KWN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 22, 0, 0), 'KWN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'KWN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'KWN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27, 0, 0), 'IRN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'IRN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'IRN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 22, 0, 0), 'IRN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'IRN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IRN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27, 0, 0), 'NTN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'NTN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'NTN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 22, 0, 0), 'NTN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'NTN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'NTN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27, 0, 0), 'IHN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'IHN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'IHN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 22, 0, 0), 'IHN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'IHN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'IHN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'PPN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 26, 0, 0), 'PPN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'PPN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'PPN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 19, 0, 0), 'PPN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 19, 0, 0), 'PPN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 19, 0, 0), 'PPN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 19, 0, 0), 'PPN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 19, 0, 0), 'PPN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'PPN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'PPN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 19, 0, 0), 'CCN+1W BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27, 0, 0), 'CCN+1M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 0, 0), 'CCN+2M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 0, 0), 'CCN+3M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'CCN+6M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 20, 0, 0), 'CCN+9M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 0, 0), 'CCN+12M BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'CCN+2Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 22, 0, 0), 'CCN+3Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 21, 0, 0), 'CCN+4Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'CCN+5Y BGN Curncy': datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 20, 0, 0)}}
```

Comment: Can you use `to_dict()` to create a copy of your dataframe that you can copy-paste into the question?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell I have updated with the dict above :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your results. When I try the code and data specified, I get the error `ValueError: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill) or backfill (bfill). Got linear`.

Comment: Since you know how many currencies and tenors you have, why not slice the big Dataframe into a dictionary of smaller ones, keyed off currency?

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions, thanks @DS_London I will attempt this now, good idea & check for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be quicker to `groupby` and then interpolate. Unfortunately, when I run your code I don't actually get the "filtered interpolated DF" that you list (perhaps you've left out some part of the interpolate where you specify that it should be 15 minute intervals?). You get a slight speedup if you use `str.startswith` instead of `str[:3]`:

```
%%timeit
for ccy in ccy_prefix:
  df[df.index.str[:3]==ccy] = df[df.index.str[:3]==ccy].interpolate(limit_direction='forward')
% 10 loops, best of 5: 25.9 ms per loop
```

As opposed to:

```
%%timeit
for ccy in ccy_prefix:
  df[df.index.str.startswith(ccy)] = df[df.index.str.startswith(ccy)].interpolate(limit_direction='forward')
% 10 loops, best of 5: 24.1 ms per loop
```

Perhaps a better solution is to create a new column with the currency prefixes and then `groupby` and `interpolate`, going from a comment provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53868976/3763302).

```
df['ccy_prefix'] = df.index.str[:3]

def interpolator(df):
  return(df.interpolate(limit_direction='forward'))
```

Then this should be quickest of them all:

```
df = df.groupby('ccy_prefix').apply(interpolator)
```

Comment: This works nicely thank you very much for your help & knowledge, It runs in about 35ms now, however I welcome any further ideas how to push this even faster, e.g. convert/ use numpy? Thank you  `pydf.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
            start = timer()
            df['ccy_prefix'] = df.index.str[:3]
            df = df.groupby('ccy_prefix').apply(self.custom_interpolator)
            df.drop(columns=['ccy_prefix'],inplace=True)
            end = timer()
            print(end - start)`

Comment: You're welcome. Would you be able to edit your original question so that your image matches the raw dataframe you provided? For example, the first value in the "bid" column in your raw data is 1192.83, but in the image it is 1192.72. I'll try and see if I can find a quicker solution then